# Set first screen as current item on launcher when user presses home?

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I'm building a launcher/home screen replacement app and I've noticed all launchers allow the user to press home to go to the first screen of the launcher. So it's obviously possible to listen to the home key for home replacement apps but I haven't been able to figure out how.

How can I listen to the home key and trigger setCurrentItem(0) when the user presses home while inside my launcher?

EDIT

I have two options until now:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if(!this.isFinishing())
    {
        if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("user_called", false))
        {
            // Si fue por una llamada del usuario eliminar bandera y no hacer nada
            Utils.setUserCalled(getApplicationContext(), false);
        }
        else
        {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The other method is this:

```
Boolean appState = false;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    appState = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if(!appState)
    {
        if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("user_called", false))
        {
            // Si fue por una llamada del usuario eliminar bandera y no hacer nada
            Utils.setUserCalled(getApplicationContext(), false);
        }
        else
        {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Both use a flag callsed user_called to know if the user started a call. My problem right now is that both methods fail when the phone rings. Is there a way to filter these cases?

Comment: you may want to look at this http://scriptedpapers.com/2013/07/26/how-to-identify-android-home-key-event-without-overriding-home-key-event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot listen to home button press since it is a system event and is not delivered to the applications. That is described in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) and also can be seen from Android codes [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#2189). The idea behind is simple - you should not be able to write an app which will hijack the phone. You can "break" the back button functionality, but not the home button functionality.

Now what the third-party launchers are usually doing is first of all declaring the launcher activity launch mode as **singleInstance** in manifest: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. Then, in addition to overriding the `onCreate()` you also override `onNewIntent()`. It is usually called instead of `onCreate()` when the activity is already running but someone fired an intent to start it again. In case of a launcher it will be called when your launcher is already running but system fires an intent to launch it because the user pressed the home button. In that function you can go to your default 'home' page.

Answer (score 1):

```
isFinishing()
```

**return TRUE** when activity is going to  **finish or destroyed.**

```
isFinishing()
```

**return FALSE** when activity is **going to  background**.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    if (!this.isFinishing()){

        //Insert code for HOME  key Event
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, this is working however I'm not sure how to differenciate when the user presses the home button and when a call is made

Answer (score 1):

Ovverriding `onUserLeaveHint()` works with me - I can make actions as soon as the user leaves using the Home button, and [it's not called](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint()) in case of incoming calls.

Don't know if this would work with a home activity.

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OnPause() of course, but you can also try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {     
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        //do things
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the previous answers, you can hook home key pressed event. However, this will work only when your app is running (i.e. displayed on your screen).

But if I understand you right, you actually want something else. You are making a custom launcher, so you would like that Android launches your app when home button is pressed. To achieve this, you need to properly set your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Here is a complete step-by-step guide, how to make a custom launcher application. Section 3  has a detailed description, how to register your application as a launcher.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358